# Do I need to use csrf protection if I am not using form tags?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, flask, csrf

I am making some forms to apply for membership in an organization. I haven't used form tag and it's just a bunch of inputs (strings, selects, and checks) and the information is sent through ajax for a Flask server. It's this safe? I am not using forms so I am not sure how to handle the csrf value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The Problem

Consider some malicious website which all it does is:

```
window.onload = function() {
  var body = {
    action: "payment", amount: 500
  }
  $.ajax("https://your-api.com", body)
}
```

So if you are logged in your site and visit this page, a request on your behalf would be made, successfully.

### The Solution

To mitigate this, add a `csrf` parameter, only known to your server and the pages it serves. Your rendered HTML pages will look like:

```
var csrf = "secret-8-digits-value-from-session-of-user";

// and on any request add this param
var body = {
  action: "payment", amount: 500, csrf: csrf
}
$.ajax("https://your-api.com", body)

// now server will verify `csrf` from *request* against `csrf` from *session*
// if no match, then reject the request.
```

Now you can visit malicious website again. They don't know your session `csrf` code. So their malicious code will not work because your server would reject the `csrf` from request.

Comment: Thank you! One last question. I get the concept now for the token but I am curious of how to make the flask server side detect if the token sent by the client is not the same that the one recorded in the flask server. I read that once you set up the csrf module from flask, all the  POST, PUT, PATCH, and DELEte methods become secure. Ajax. what kind of method use to send the data?

Comment: I am not familiar with the flask server side. But that module surely expects the `csrf` param to exist in all request, probably in the header of the request. As far as the server is concerned, an ajax request is the same as a `<form>`  request. So if you know what hidden fields you should add to your forms so that the csrf module will work, then you should use the same fields on the ajax request.